# I take careful/ caution attitude or I am an attentive?

Tags: grammar, terminology

I am writing my English resume, but my grammar seems not correct,

> **I take a careful and cautious attitude** toward the work and handle it properly.

How can I make a sentence more fluently?

Should it be:

> I take careful/caution attitude

Or:

> I am an attentive

Answer (score 1):

The standard resume jargon for "a careful and cautious attitude towards the work" is **detail-oriented**.

That said, I would prefer to encounter your phrase in a resume rather than the jargon. But these days, you never know if a human being is reading the resume; it may be a bot.

Answer (score -1):

You don't ***take*** an attitude, you ***have*** an attitude.

> I **have** a careful attitude toward work...

As for "I am an attentive," that needs a noun:

> I am an attentive **worker** and I handle my work properly

Comment: You're revealing your AmE roots, J.R. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22take%20an%20attitude%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Interesting! Thanks. It sounded awkward to me, but maybe that's just me.